# Central_logger integration with Heroku Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, heroku, mongohq

I am trying to setup central_logger (https://github.com/customink/central_logger) to my heroku app. Can someone please point me to a tutorial or lay out steps on how I can achieve this? The readme is quite clear but doesn't say anything about heroku integration except for point 4 which says

**For use with Heroku you need to prevent the rails_log_stdout plugin from being added by Heroku:
mkdir vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout
touch vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout/.gitkeep**

I dont quite understand this without some more context. It will be much appreciated.

APologies if the question is ambiguous.

Thanks!
Satyam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discussion on [this pull request](https://github.com/customink/central_logger/pull/11) should help.

Basically, Heroku automatically injects `rails_log_stdout`, as you can see in the output from doing a git push:

```
-----> Rails plugin injection
       Injecting rails_log_stdout
       Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
```

You have to tell Heroku not to inject `rails_log_stdout` by making that plugin:

```
mkdir vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout
touch vendor/plugins/rails_log_stdout/.gitkeep
```

You should also be using a Heroku-compatible version of `central_logger`. I use Heroku and keep my fork working: https://github.com/turadg/central_logger/